# Flutter: Can't Find String.xml file

Tags: flutter, string.xml

I want to use `flutter_share_me 0.9.1` Plug-In. but I can't find `String.xml` file in my project Folder

[image] [image: folder].

Comment: create the file if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create `strings.xml` under `res/values` Directory and add this code to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- Replace "343254889799245" with your Facebook App ID here. -->
    <string name="facebook_app_id">343254889799245</string>
</resources>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: The directory path is android/app/src/main/res/values

Comment: not strings.xml?